# c - lkm using netfilter, trouble with strcmp

Tags: c, strcmp, netlink

I am having a lot of trouble with this problem. If I could figure this out, it would solve several problems for me, but I have been unable to figure this out.

This is an LKM project using netlink

So I have a line in this project

```
    printk(KERN_INFO "Netlink received msg payload:%s\n", (char *)nlmsg_data(nlh));
```

which obviously prints the payload to KERN_INFO.

But I need to determine what the payload is.

```
   "%s", (char *)nlmsg_data(nlh)
```

So I am trying my best to figure this out and all I've got so far, which doesn't work is:

```
    if (strcmp("%s\n", "hide") == 0)
```

But where do I put

```
    (char *)nlmsg_data(nlh)
```

How can I write this in a way which will work? AM I going about this the wrong way? Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: `if (strcmp("%s\n", ...` -> `%s` is the format specifier and is `printf` and `scanf` stuff,  to compare with `strcmp` you want something like `if (strcmp((char *)nlmsg_data(nlh), "hide") == 0)`

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Probably tried everything BUT that. Really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Please look at the Linux man page for ```strcmp```.